# How to pass complicated structure for one of fields in postman?

Tags: swagger, postman

I have swagger structure, which has complicated structure for one of fields :

```
"values": {
  "date": {
    "date": "2021-01-15",
    "time": "12:30am"
  }
}
```

and making testing in postman I wonder in which way to pass this parameter, as value is long string ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: When adding new parameter in Postman request I need in text input set value from my topic, which is structure data. I do not how to make it. Is my question clear now?